# discord.py invoke subcommand

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Basically I want to invoke a subcommand. If I have this code here, with fun being the subcommand:

```
@client.group()
async def help(ctx):
    if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
        await ctx.send("Hello")
@help.command()
async def fun(ctx):
    if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
        await ctx.send("Fun")
```

I want to have another command, for example:
`async def invoke_fun(ctx)`, which invokes the subcommand fun, but not the help command.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this:

```py
@client.command()
async def invoke_fun(ctx)
    command = client.get_command("help fun")
    ctx.command = command
    ctx.invoked_subcommand = command
    await client.invoke(ctx)
```